# php bin/console assets:install --symlink not working

Tags: orocommerce

I am trying to change the logo following: https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/how-to/how-to-replace-the-logo/ . I followed the steps to create an empty bundle, the bundle shows up in the symfony "active bundles" list so it seems to have registered correctly.
The theme definition in: Resources/views/layouts/my_theme/theme.yml :

```
label:  My Theme
logo:   bundles/companytheme/my_theme/images/mainlogo.svg
parent: default
groups: [ commerce ]
```

also seems to work, the "My Theme" is available in the backend>System>Configuration>Commerce>Design>Theme
But the logo doesn't work, there is just nothing. So I looked into public/bundles/ and noticed there is no symlink to the Resource files of my bundle.

Running

```
php bin/console assets:install --symlink
```

works, but it only shows the symlinks that are already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make sure that you put your logo image into public folder like:
`NEW_BUNDLE/package/Resources/public/img/logo.svg/`.

Then add a `logo` property with value from public folder: `bundles/NEW_BUNDLE/images/mainlogo.svg` into `theme.yml` and clear the application cache and rerunning the command:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
php bin/console assets:install --symlink
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I still don't know what I missed, I did it all over again following your steps and that actually worked